# get date of next 4 days

Tags: php

The following code worked before, but failed to get the next 4 days of today 2011-11-04

```
$draw_date = '2011-11-04';
$ts = strtotime($draw_date) + 86400*4;

$ddate = date('Y-m-d', $ts);
echo $ddate;
```

The code above print 2011-11-07, but what I expected is 2011-11-08. It works if I set draw_date = '2011-10-04' or '2011-12-04'. Very weird! Can anyone explain why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Indeed to me it prints 2011-11-08.

Comment: I get the [intended result](http://codepad.org/P0HrYmNN). `2011-11-08`.

Comment: It also prints `2011-11-08` to me. It may be a timezone problem. Have you rerun your code?

Comment: Yes. It's timezone problem. DST ends on 11/06.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget there's a DST switchover on November 6th. That makes 4days-from-now actually be 86400*4 + 3600 for the extra hour.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I just figured it out a minute ago. So the safety way is to do it like Kamil mentioned, strtotime('+4 day', $ts).

Comment: Yep. Doing direct date math with 86400 and whatnot should only be done on UTC dates preferably, and even those can fail when you take leap seconds into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$ts = strtotime($draw_date) ;
strtotime('+4 day', $ts);
```

Comment: Thanks that works. But can you explain why my code does NOT work?

Comment: try set time zone before your operation: date_default_timezone_set('..'); list of supported timezone is in: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php, maybe something changed in your system..